# On the existence of scalar multiplication of free vectors?

Tags: analytic-geometry

When we study analytical geometry at the undergraduate level we define free vectors as oriented line segments. This raises a problem when we try to formalize the multiplication of a free vector by a scalar. In order to elaborate on that, denote by $\mathbb V^3$ the set of free vectors. How can we show there exists a unique map

$$\cdot : \mathbb R\times \mathbb V^3\rightarrow \mathbb V^3, (\lambda, \overrightarrow{v})\mapsto \lambda \overrightarrow{v}$$

such that:

(1) $0\cdot \overrightarrow{v}=\overrightarrow{0}$

(2) $\lambda \overrightarrow{v}$ has the same direction as $\overrightarrow{v}$

(3) $\lambda \overrightarrow{v}$ has the same orientation as $\overrightarrow{v}$ if $\lambda>0$ and opposite orientation when $\lambda<0$

(4) $|\lambda \overrightarrow{v}|=|\lambda||\overrightarrow{v}|.$

Back in the past I found a book that proved this but I ended up forgetting which book was that. Do you know how to prove the existence of such a map or where I can find the proof?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention in a comment that you want to use the abstract Euclidean space $E$ rather than the coordinate space $\mathbb R^3$.
The space $E$ has the nice property that every point in the space has equal status, unlike the space $\mathbb R^3$ in which one point, $(0,0,0),$ is singled out as the origin.

But this presents you with a special difficulty when you try to define your scalar product. The definition of the scalar product requires the existence of a unique vector
$\vec 0$ such that for any vector $\vec v,$ no matter which you choose,

$$ 0 (\vec v) = \vec 0.$$

The question then is: which vector in $\mathbb V^3$ is $\vec 0$?

There can only be one zero vector, hence you must single out just **one** of your "free vectors" to be the zero vector. As soon as you do so, you have established a special point in your space $E,$ the same way that the origin is a special point in $R^3.$
In order to define a scalar product on your "free vectors," you are going to have to give up one of the most significant differences between your space and $R^3.$

Note that once you find $\vec 0$ such that $0 (\vec v) = \vec 0,$
the property $|\lambda \vec{v}|=|\lambda||\vec{v}|$
implies that $|\vec 0|=|0\vec v|=|0||\vec v| = 0.$
That is, both endpoints of $\vec 0$ must be the same point.

As long as you are willing to identify $\vec 0$ as a particular point in $E,$
you might as well call that point the origin of $E.$
You can then define $\lambda \vec v$ for any free vector $\vec v$ as follows:

For any point $p \in E,$ if $p = \vec 0$ then $\lambda p = \vec 0$;
otherwise define $\lambda p$ as a point on the line through $\vec 0$ and $p$
such that the distance from $\vec 0$ to $\lambda p$ is $|\lambda|$ times the distance from $\vec 0$ to $p$ and such that $\vec 0$ is strictly between $p$ and $\lambda p$ if and only if $\lambda < 0.$

Then for any free vector $\vec v$, if $\vec v$ is the directed line segment from
$p \in E$ to $q \in E,$
let $\lambda \vec v$ be the directed line segment from $\lambda p$ to $\lambda q.$

You can check that this satisfies all four of your properties.

Answer (score 1):

I'll write my answer under the presumption that by the superscript $3$ on $\mathbb V^3$ you are working in $\mathbb R^3$. Also, given $p,q \in \mathbb R^3$ I'll use $\overline{pq}$ or $\overline{p,q}$ as the notation for the free vector with initial endpoint $p$ and terminal endpoint $q$.

---

Regarding existence, one construction goes like this.

For each $p \in \mathbb R^3$ let
$$\mathbb V^3_p = \{\overline{pq} \mid q \in \mathbb R^3\}
$$
Also, let $T_p$ be the translation of $\mathbb R^3$ which takes the origin to $p$, defined by
$$T_p(x)=x+p
$$
Here, of course, I am using ordinary vector addition on $\mathbb R^3$.

Then scalar multiplication can be defined on $\mathbb V^3$ by defining it separately on $\mathbb V^3_p$ for each $p$:

- If $p=0$ then for each $\vec v = \overline{0x} \in \mathbb V^3_0$ define $r \vec v = \overline{0,rx}$. This is essentially ordinary scalar multiplication, carried out on the terminal endpoint of free vectors with initial endpoint $0$.
- If $p \ne 0$ then for each $\vec v = \overline{p,x} \in \mathbb V^3_0$ define
  $$r \vec v = T_p ( r T_p^{-1}(\vec v)) = \overline{p,p + r (x-p)}
  $$
  Think of this as changing coordinates so that $p$ becomes the origin, and then in those new coordinates using ordinary scalar multiplication to define scalar multiplication as usual.

---

However, uniqueness is false. For example, having first defined the scalar multiplication above, which I'll denote $r \cdot \vec v$, I could do something silly to get another scalar multiplication $r * \vec v$. For example, I could pick two points $p_1,p_2$, define $S$ to be the translation of $\mathbb R^3$ that takes $p_1$ to $p_2$, and then:

- If $p \not\in \{p_1,p_2\}$ then $r * \vec v = r \cdot \vec v$
- If $p=p_1$ then $r * \vec v = S(r \cdot \vec v)$
- If $p=p_2$ then $r * \vec v = S^{-1}(r \cdot \vec v)$

If you want something unique, you're going to have to impose an additional condition. One natural condition to impose would be that for each $p \in \mathbb R^3$, if $\vec v \in \mathbb V^3_p$ then $r \vec v \in \mathbb V^3_p$. In other words, the scalar multiplication operation preserves the initial point of the free vector. Under this condition, the formula I gave above is the unique example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll check it carefully. At first, I meant $\mathbb V^3$ as the abstract space from Euclidean geometry. But I got the idea. Even in this abstract setting I can use coordinate systems for lines which are provided axiomatically.

Comment: Well, to say that $\mathbb V^3$ is the space of free vectors, i.e. the space of oriented line segments in $\mathbb R^3$, is inconsistent with saying that $\mathbb V^3$ is the "abstract space from Euclidean geometry" which we may noawadays identify with $\mathbb R^3$

Comment: Yep, the terminology was not right. For me $\mathbb V^3$ is a quotient of $\mathbb E\times \mathbb E$ where $\mathbb E$ is the abstract space from Euclidean geometry. I really meant that $\mathbb V^3$ was not $\mathbb R^3$.